# React router navigation does not work

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I have implemented a react JS test application with react router in ES6 but it does not seem to work. The code snippet i below:

```
app.js
-------

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Routes from './routes';

ReactDOM.render(Routes, document.getElementById('react-container'));

routes.js
---------

import React from 'react';
import { DefaultRoute, Link, Route, RouteHandler,Router } from 'react-router';
import Page1 from './page1';
import Home from './home';
import { IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

let routes = 
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Home}>
      <Route path="page1" component={ Page1 }/>
    </Route>
  </Router>

export default routes

home.js
-------

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './components/header';

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

page1.js
--------

import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Page1 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Page 1 </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Navigating to "/" and "/page1" seem to land in a page indicating the header section alone. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Any way you could show us the Page1 component?

Comment: @NaderDabit The page1.js is also included above.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you want to render `page1` to show up when navigating to `/`? If so, the [docs seem to indicate](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/basics/IndexRoutes.md) that you'll need an IndexRoute to have `/` route to `page1` by default:

```
let routes = (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Home}>
      <IndexRoute component={Page1} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to test this, but I think that without providing a **history**, react-router won't be able to read the URL location. So it would make sense for it to only render the `/` path.

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
...
</Router>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this, combined with an index route is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should leave out the `constructor` when it's not doing anything. The default constructor is:

```
constructor(...args) {
  super(...args);
}
```

So the implicit props arguments aren't getting passed into `Home` component.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I removed all the constructors since it was not doing anything but still the navigation does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers touch on these individually, but I think you need to combine an index route, browser history, and turn your export into a react component like this:

```
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

const Routes = () => {
   return (
       <Router history={browserHistory}>
           <Route path="/" component={Home}>
               <IndexRoute component={Page1}/>
           </Route>
       </Router>
   )
}

export default Routes;
```

This should be valid for the latest version of React Router (2.0.0-rc5)